# Nonetype is not iterable when updating dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am pretty new to python and as a project to push myself, I decided to create a simple framework with an updatable user:password dictionary. *This is still a work in progress!* The problem exists when creating a new user id and then trying to access that user id. I am using python 3.7.

Here is the error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  line 37, in 
    if account in accounts:
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

```
import sys
accounts = {'Trace': 'Jollyrancher5', 'Brian': 'Kitties82', 'Taylor': 'Flower15'}

while True:
    print('Please select an option.\n1. Create new account.\n2. Enter existing account.')
    choice = input()
    if choice == '1':
        print('Please enter an account name')
        new_account = input()
        if new_account not in accounts.keys():
            print('Please enter a password.')
            new_pass = input()
            accounts = accounts.update({new_account: new_pass})
            print('Your new User ID is: ' + new_account + '.')
            print('Your new password is: ' + new_pass + '.')
            print('Please store this information for safe keeping.')
            print('Type OK to continue.')
            while True:
                next = input()
                if next == 'OK' or next == 'ok':
                    break
                else:
                    print('Invalid entry. Please type OK.')
        else:
            print('Account name taken. Please enter a different account name.')
    elif choice == '2':
        break
    else:
        print('Not a valid entry.')

account = ''
password = ''
denial = 0
while True:
    print('Please enter User ID.')
    account = input()
    if account in accounts:
        break
    else:
        print('User ID not recognized.')

while True:
    print('Please enter password.')
    password = input()
    if password == accounts[account]:
        break
    else:
        password != accounts[account]
        denial += 1
        if denial == 3:
            print('Account locked.')
            input()
            sys.exit()
print('Access Granted.\nYour account balance is $1,000,000.00.')
input()
```

Comment: Line 13 returns `None` just use `accounts.update(...)` not `accounts = accounts.update(...)`

Comment: `accounts = accounts.update({...})` -> `accounts.update({...})`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in line no 13:

```
accounts = accounts.update({new_account: new_pass})
```

This returns `None` as the update is done in place. [[see docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update)] Instead use:

```
accounts.update({new_account: new_pass})
```

It will perform the update no need to reassign the value.

Comment: Ah, so simple, how did I not realize that. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Jab I got my python gold-tag-badge finally :-) and 16k finally too :-)

Answer (score 1):

Remove this line:-

```
`accounts = accounts.update({new_account: new_pass})`
```

add this line:-

```
`while True:
      print('Please enter User ID.')
      account = input()
      accounts.update({new_account:new_pass})
      if account in accounts:`
```

this error is caused because your dictionary was not getting updated, and that's why the first value it was recieving was None hence a NoneType error was generated.

Upvote if you understand my answer.